# Hibernate + Herança

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, netbeans

Estou tentando a algum tempo uma solução para meu problema. Já pesquisei bastante mas nada me explica com clareza o que eu preciso.

Portanto criei uma aplicação de exemplo e estou disponibilizando ela a partir deste link:
[Applicação](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2mw7Hlip92vTGIwU3FoYTFUZDg/edit?usp=sharing)

Para executar esta aplicação basta utilizar a IDE NetBeans e criar um DB MySql com o seguinte nome: "testeHeranca".

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Tenho duas entidades, Participante e Emitente. A classe Emitente extende a classe participante. Por Exemplo:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "participante")
public class Participante implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String nome;
    @Column(name = "documento", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String documento;
    ...
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "emitente")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Emitente extends Participante{

    @Column(name = "cargo", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String cargo;
    ...
}
```

Suponha-se que eu tenho um participante já cadastrado no meu banco de dados, se eu quiser cadastrar um novo emitente a partir deste participante já existente, como eu deveria proceder? O Hibernate faz isso pra mim? Com o teste que passei no exemplo isso não acontece.

Comment: Olá Gilvan, seu problema é bastante interessante. Pelo que entendi você busca "promover" uma superclasse para um dos seus subtipos. Não tenho certeza se existe uma solução para isso em JPA (talvez haja uma solução específica do Hibernate). *Os work-arounds* em que consigo pensar são: 1) Fazer um *insert* manual na tabela `emitente` reaproveitando o `id` do `participante` com sql nativo ou 2) Remover o participante e inserir um emitente (o que pode ser problemático devido a FKs, principalmente com ids auto-incrementáveis).

Comment: Exatamente! No momento eu estou criando um insert manual na tabela emitente com Query Nativa. Mas estou pensando muito na possibilidade de abandonar a herança e utilizar agregação como foi a sugestão um dos usuário que respondeu! Obrigado por enquanto, vou continuar a pesquisando e estudando qual a melhor solução. Conto com a ajuda de todos! Obrigado]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embora não conheça todos os detalhes do Hibernate e outras implementações JPA, pois cada uma tem suas particularidades, não creio ser possível fazer incluir parte de um relacionamento de herança.

Pensando que o JPA trabalha com uma espécie limitada de polimorfismo, isso seria como mudar o tipo do objeto.

Nessa situação em específico, uma alternativa viável seria alterar o tipo de relacionamento de herança para agregação, isto é, onde `Emitente` tem um atributo do tipo `Participante`. Dessa forma as tabelas não precisam ser alteradas e você pode incluir as entidades em separado a qualquer momento.

Outras alternativas existem, como já mencionadas no comentário do Anthony Accioly:

1. Incluir o emitente via JDBC ou Query Nativa e depois ler via JPA
2. Remover o participante e incluí-lo novamente como um emitente

Comment: Opa @utluiz, se puder emendar uma pequena observação (mais semântica do que qualquer coisa, para alguém que não conheça a API do JPA) para o item 1 o usuário não precisa nem usar a API do JDBC diretamente, basta um `entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT ...").executeUpdate();`. É claro que por debaixo dos panos o JPA está usando JDBC, mas não há necessidade de criar um `Statement` ou algo do gênero.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Muito boa observação. É sempre bom deixar claro essas coisas.

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta, acredito que vou seguir o caminho da agregação, herança funciona bem desde que eu não venha a utilizar a entidade pai! Obrigado até então, vou continuar as minhas pesquisas e estudos para definir qual será a melhor opção para minha solução! Muito obrigado!

Comment: ok, obrigado pela ajuda de todos. Cheguei a conclusão que será melhor utilizar agregação! Abraços